Rotation of 3D object relative direction
I have a light that is facing a direction that is based on the lights position.
I want a object to be rotated so that it is facing the same direction as the light. The objects rotation is determined by a rotation around the x, y and z axis.
Im wondering how to achive this?
I have tried the following equation that i found online, without success:
m_rotation.z = -atan2(sqrtf(powf(rot.y, 2) + powf(rot.z, 2)), rot.x);
m_rotation.x = -atan2(rot.y, rot.z);


Please elaborate "a light that is facing a direction that is based on the lights position". Is it directed from its position to (0,0,0), the coordinate origin? Is it facing towards a different position than (0,0,0)? Please explain the symptoms of the failure. How do you test your code? Please provide example position and desired outcome. Please explain what you try to do with the x/z rotation. If, for example you rotate a x-facing beam first around the z axis and then around the global x axis, it will not point towards the used position. Rotate first around global y and then global z.

Global y could be considered local x for an x-facing beam. I suspect that your problem is with that difference. So please describe the involved coordinate systems. At least the one in which the lights position is given (I assume global xyz) and the system in which the calculated rotations are applied. Note that I expect that one to be different from global at the latest after the application of the first of the roations. Please describe the meaning of rot.y, rot.z, rot.x. The formula you found probably works (if applied correctly) if they are light position coordinates, weirdly named.

Alternative, rotate around global z first, then around local x. Local x axis is however different from initial local x now. Initial local x of the beam might be identical to global y.

Please define the facing direction you arrive at if you apply the calculated rotatsion of 0,0. Please define the facing direction if you apply a rotation of z=45 degrees and x=90 degrees. That should allow to determine the local coordinate system and order of rotations you are using.
